# Quarkus native deployment to Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, quarkus

It's challenging deploying natively packaged quarkus application to docker. I deployed successfully without a database and flyway connectivity but now I am getting error after deploying with postgres and flyway.

My property file is as follows and I have set those in the environment variables of Heroku app instance:

```
quarkus.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
%prod.quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_DB_HOST}:5432/${POSTGRES_DB_NAME}
%prod.quarkus.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_DB_USER}
%prod.quarkus.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_DB_PASS}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818527+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:135)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818583+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818639+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818729+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818785+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818882+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818935+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.818980+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:390)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819072+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:372)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819118+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819169+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:65)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819252+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819294+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819341+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-03-14T17:07:08.819422+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:460)
2020-03-14T17:07:16.471038+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-03-14 17:07:16,470 ERROR [io.qua.application] (main) Failed to start application: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.isCurveSupported([B)Z [symbol: Java_sun_security_ec_ECKeyPairGenerator_isCurveSupported or Java_sun_security_ec_ECKeyPairGenerator_isCurveSupported___3B]
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian.
I chose to use container for deployment because deploying Application JAR file of Quarkus to Heroku is still not working for me.